# Uso do Display do CSS

Tags: css

Eu reparei que eu ando usando bastante o `display:none` para retirar blocos de códigos de uma página. Faço isso por instruções de superiores, mas eu sempre acreditei que é uma prática que pode afetar a performance dos sites desenvolvidos.

**A pergunta:**

**O uso excessivo de** `display:none` **pode afetar o sistema de alguma forma?**

Lembrando que são sites que raramente sofrem de manutenções.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O display:none em si não afeta o desempenho do site ja que o css é processado pelo cliente e não o servidor, no entanto o conteudo escondido é sim um disperdício de recurso, já que ele será enviado para o usuário independente da sua utilização.

Este overhead pode afetar tanto os custos da empresa como o requisito minimo do cliente. É uma prática comum em CSS e JS fazer uso da versão minima (min), que reduz o tamanho do arquivo facilitando o acesso a ele e diminuindo o consumo de banda.

Para grandes sites com muitos acessos essa redução tem impacto significante, da mesma forma que para clientes que usam smartphones com internet móvel.